# How to get the float values for a sympy point?

Tags: python, sympy

I have the following piece of code

```py
from sympy import Point, Line

l1 = Line((3,5,-2), (1,-1,4))
p1 = Point3D((3, 7, 9))

intersection_p = p1.intersection(l1)[0]
print(intersection_p)
```

I get

```
Point3D(30/7, 62/7, -41/7)
```

But, I want the float values, not the rationals.

```
[4.285714285714286, 8.857142857142858, -5.857142857142857]
```

I've done this which gives me the desired output.

```py
intersection1 = [float(i) for i in p1.intersection(l1)[0].args]
```

But I was wondering if there is any sympy method that converts/extracts the `Point3D` object's coordinate values as `float`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `evalf()`, just as you would do with regular symbolic expressions. You can use `tuple(p1.evalf())` or `list(p1.evalf())` to have the numbers in a more standard Python way.

```py
from sympy import Point3D, sqrt, pi

p1 = Point3D((sqrt(2), 7, pi/2))

print(p1)
print(p1.evalf())
```

Output:

```py
Point3D(sqrt(2), 7, pi/2)
Point3D(1.4142135623731, 7.0, 1.5707963267949)
```

Note that `evalf()` accepts a parameter indicating the number of digits.